# Add a button to Show-Hide based on Select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a button (input type="button") to the dropdown. I tried to add a button but it didn't work. Is it possible to add a button so it will go like this: select an option, click a button, show Div?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
$('#dropDown, #dropDown2').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();
    });   
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
    });
</script>

<select id="dropDown">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="item1">One</option>
  <option value="item2">Two</option>
  <option value="item3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="view" target="_self">
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item1">
  <p>First content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item2">
  <p>Second content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item3">
  <p>Third content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, on click of the button, grab the value of the select, hide all the drop-down-show-hide, and then show the one related to the dropdown value.

Comment: What part of this problem are you having an issue implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a something quick that should get you going.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var lastSelected;
  $('input').click(function() {
   $('#' + lastSelected).hide();
    lastSelected = $('#dropDown').val();
    $('#' + lastSelected).show()
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="item1">One</option>
  <option value="item2">Two</option>
  <option value="item3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="view" target="_self">
<div class="hidden" id="item1">
  <p>First content</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="item2">
  <p>Second content</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="item3">
  <p>Third content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

The trick is to declare a variable at global scope (outside any function) and use it to hold a value.

That value will be set on `#dropDown` change... And used on `#dropDownButton` click.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
  var dropdownValue;
  $('#dropDown').change(function(){
    dropdownValue = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#dropDownButton').click(function(){
    $(".drop-down-show-hide").hide();
    $("#"+dropdownValue).show();
    console.log(dropdownValue);
  });
});
</script>

<select id="dropDown">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="item1">One</option>
  <option value="item2">Two</option>
  <option value="item3">Three</option>
</select>
<input id="dropDownButton" type="button" value="view" target="_self">
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item1">
  <p>First content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item2">
  <p>Second content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item3">
  <p>Third content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the event handler for the view button each time the value for the select changes.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
$('#dropDown, #dropDown2').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();
    });   
    var x = this;
    $('#view').off();
    $('#view').click(function(e){
    $('#' + x.value).show();
    });
});
    });
</script>

<select id="dropDown">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="item1">One</option>
  <option value="item2">Two</option>
  <option value="item3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="view" target="_self" id='view'>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item1">
  <p>First content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item2">
  <p>Second content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item3">
  <p>Third content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listening to the `onClick` event of the button instead of `onChange`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function() {
    $('#dropDown').find('option').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();
    });   
    $('#' + $('#dropDown').val()).show();
});
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js">  </script>

<select id="dropDown">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="item1">One</option>
  <option value="item2">Two</option>
  <option value="item3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="view" target="_self">
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item1">
  <p>First content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item2">
  <p>Second content</p>
</div>
<div class="drop-down-show-hide" id="item3">
  <p>Third content</p>
</div>
```